# UWF how to and not working

Tags: server, 20.04, firewall, lts, ufw

How do I use UFW for firewall and how can I see if it is working, I don't think it is, I tried to block my computer from accessing my website using ufw and it still allowed me to access it. I am using Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS,

Comment: Can Some one help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
 sudo ufw status

 sudo ufw default DENY

 sudo ufw enable
```

Then `sudo reboot`. The easiest way is to install ufw and check back often.